# Change URL structure

Tags: wordpress, redirect

I have used the path `example.com/محصولات/product-name` for my product pages, but I want to use the path `example.com/product/product-name`. So I want to change the `محصولات` to `product` in the path. What should I do?

I used the plugin of Rankmath and created code in `.htaccess` but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Please do the following steps:

Go to `Settings->permalinks` / in Persian version it mentioned: `تنظیمات-> پیوند یکتا` and change `Custom base` to `/product/%product_cat%/`

in case it is not working:

1. delete or rename `.htaccess` file
2. go to `Settings->permalinks` / in the Persian version it mentions:
   `تنظیمات-> پیوند یکتا`
3. check `Custom base` value.
4. click on `save changes` / in the Persian verion click on `ذخیره تنظیمات` (after you click on `save change` `.htaccess` will generate again by WordPress)